# How to update Virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I'm trying to update virtualbox. The system is updated. The site of virtualbox says just to download the latest version and just run it normally, but when I do that, it only opens the ubuntu software and nothing more. So, how do I update virtualbox?

**Updated:**

For anyone that reaches this question, there's an updated way to update virtualbox since `apt-key` and `add-apt-repository` will be deprecated. Read this tutorial at DigitalOcean's blog: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-handle-apt-key-and-add-apt-repository-deprecation-using-gpg-to-add-external-repositories-on-ubuntu-22-04

Reading this excellent tutorial, you'll learn how to add an external repository to update virtualbox and other packages, and for anybody who tried to install virtualbox following the instructions in the virtualbox site and failed (via apt), you'll know why it didn't work. Very good tutorial indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install latest VirtualBox 6.1.28 from the virtualbox.org site open terminal and execute the following commands:

```
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -

sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian focal contrib"

sudo apt-get install virtualbox-6.1
```